# Problems with getting and changing NSMutableArray objects

Tags: memory, object, nsmutablearray, nscopying, copywithzone

I have a NSMutableArray called **organisations** which is an array of custom objects of a class I subclassed from NSObject, this subclass is called **NSXOrganisation**. This subclass DOES implement **NSCopy** like so:

```
@interface NSXOrganisation : NSObject <NSCopying>

...

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    if (copy) 
    {
        [copy setPropertyOne:[[[self getPropertyOne] copyWithZone:zone] autorelease]];           
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Now, I alloc & init the array like so:

```
organisations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:organisationsArray copyItems:YES];
```

This all works fine. For the sake of testing **the array has 2 objects in it**.

Next, when a method is called, I update an object in the array like so:

```
- (void)updateOrganisation
{
    [[organisations objectAtIndex:0] setConsumerKey:[tfPropertyOne stringValue]];
}
```

Where *tfPropertyOne** is a NSTextField on the display (binded properly etc). This also works fine, as I have tested with NSLog and it outputs the correct result. I then call a display method on a different index in the array to view its relevant details:

```
- (void)displayOrganisation:
{
    [tfPropertyOne setStringValue:[[organisations objectAtIndex:index] getPropertyOne]];
}
```

**index** is a local NSInteger and is not the problem. I then call the same update method on this object, which apparently works fine also (using NSLog to test).

Finally, when I make a call to go back and display the first object in the array **[self displayOrganisation:0]** the call works successfully, but my app crashes when calling **getPropertyOne**.

This is the error in the Mac Console:

```
...: Invalid memory access of location 0x3bcfd069 eip=0x90c1cd5c
```

And this is from the crash report:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x90c1cd4b objc_msgSend + 27
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x943da945 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 57
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x906503ae __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 12238
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x906a70dc _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 108
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9072821c _CFLogvEx + 124
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x9445d221 NSLogv + 136
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x9445d194 NSLog + 27
7   co.nz.fdl.XeroConnect           0x1b5b4872 -[PrefsController displayOrganisation:] + 194 (PrefsController.mm:229)
```

Can anyone help? Am I accessing / creating / storing the objects into the array incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by changing my header file for the custom object.

Original:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *propertyOne;
```

Working:

```
@property (copy) NSString *propertyOne;
```

This whole issue was generally down to my lack of Objective-C knowledge (hence why I'm still learning!). Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access an object that has already been released.
Check your autorelease calls.

Comment: I have no autorelease calls in my code so it's not that unfortunately.